# Apache Solr reblance shards version 6.6.x

Tags: solr, lucene, sharding, solrcloud

We have to increase shards of Solr for performance improvement. For this purpose, I have found a guide at [GitHub](https://github.com/bloomreach/solrcloud-rebalance-api) about re-balance API but unfortunately it is not working as its source code is also not found. 
How can I create new shards; it should be auto scaling so that if shard size is increase then two new shards should be created. Further, I also want to balance shards i.e., if there are more documents in one shard and these should be migrated to other shard to make them balance.

Is there any builtin support in Solr (cloud) for these objectives ? How can I achieve the goals ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [SPLITSHARD](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-splitshard) API call in Solr. It will give you an ability to take an existing shard and break it into two pieces which are written to disk as two (new) shards. The original shard will continue to contain the same data as-is but it will start re-routing requests to the new shards.

You could use `ranges` parameters to define the ranges of documents that you want to move to a new shard. Another useful thing would be to `split.key`

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way, to trigger this command based on some requirements - like size of shard and this what you would need to build yourself